# Duplicate GET requests - Rails & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I'm trying a solution to resolve a duplication of requests happening in my Ruby on Rails 6 project deployed to Heroku.

This seems to occur when those anchors with hyperlinks are used, so it loads 2x.

As a result, it ends up generating duplicate logs because it also calls the controller (GET -> Controller -> Model -> View).

Below are some logs that prove the duplicate request:

```rb
caio-agiani in ~ via ⬢ v14.21.3 took 10m 37s ❯ heroku logs -a levante-web -t | grep 2804:7f0:b8c2:13f:8755:4a1e:74b8:x735,172.71.10.17          
2024-03-31T02:32:36.318790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/levante/search?query=caioagiani" host=app request_id=3e84b5d5-b478-41aa-b1e8-218838f37ca1 fwd="2804:7f0:b8c2:13f:8755:4a1e:74b8:x735,172.71.10.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=426ms status=200 bytes=12075 protocol=https
2024-03-31T02:32:57.648033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/levante/search?query=caioagiani" host=app request_id=f17c6635-3541-4153-8283-3811659ff00a fwd="2804:7f0:b8c2:13f:8755:4a1e:74b8:x735,172.71.10.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=330ms status=200 bytes=12077 protocol=https
2024-03-31T02:33:01.813927+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/levante/shop/index" host=app request_id=cc5dd643-41c3-45e9-bffa-a73ed617d0b0 fwd="2804:7f0:b8c2:13f:8755:4a1e:74b8:x735,172.71.10.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=42ms status=200 bytes=25575 protocol=https
2024-03-31T02:33:02.145246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/levante/shop/index" host=app request_id=7bdfadad-273e-4b8a-ab88-4f0422ececaf fwd="2804:7f0:b8c2:13f:8755:4a1e:74b8:x735,172.71.10.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=39ms status=200 bytes=25564 protocol=https
```

[image]

PS: Could this be linked to Turbolink/Load or some internal Rails script like ujs? I have evidence that yes, as I have another application in production using exactly the same setup, however, 1 uses the conventional rails native import scripts and css template (javascript_include_tag, javascript_pack_tag, stylesheet_pack_tag) and the other uses simple HTML meta tags

- I've already tested it in a local environment and this doesn't happen.
- I saw some comments about Serviceworker, but I didn't validate it 100%.
- There is no Loadbalance/Nginx configuration. Direct environment between Heroku with Node/Ruby Buildpacks and the RoR project.